# Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found, windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

So after installing VSCode and Python 3.7.4 (64 bit) I really struggle to make the "python interactive" work.

I have installed the Python extension in VScode, also `jupyter` and `jupyter-lab` but I keep getting the error "Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found." when I try to run a cell/a line.

I am running Windows 10, using `pip3`

Comment: Well, your python environment must have jupyter-notebook installed. Did you install it with pip or conda?

Comment: I am using pip .

Comment: If you start up a terminal / command prompt from the python environment that you have selected in vscode can you run the following command:
"python -m jupyter notebook --version"
The results of that should tell you if your environment is ready to use the interactive features.

Comment: I get `Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.`

Answer (score 6):

What did the trick was, that a few packages were outdated.

Firstly I had to uninstall pyzmq and install it again.

Then I ran `pip3 install --upgrade nbconvert`.

I also did `pip install --upgrade pywin32==224` but I think the upper two solved the problem.

Lesson learned: Never use conda/pip together!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to install anaconda first and start your notebook from an anaconda terminal.

Comment: conda/pip just have a thing with messing each other up sometimes