# Visual Studio Code cannot start Python Interactive Window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm losing my mind with this. I've been trying to do a clean install of Anaconda and VS Code, and now whenever I try to open a Python Interactive window it closes immediately, the only error I get is "Jupyter cannot be started. Error attempting to locate jupyter:"
Trying to create a new blank jupyter notebook and run simple code gives me

```
Error: Jupyter cannot be started. Error attempting to locate jupyter:
at A.startServer (c:\Users\[]\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\out\client\extension.js:1:781100)
at async A.ensureServerAndNotebookImpl (c:\Users\[]\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\out\client\extension.js:1:780555)
at async A.ensureServerAndNotebook (c:\Users\shoosh\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\out\client\extension.js:1:780356)
at async A.submitCode (c:\Users\[]\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\out\client\extension.js:1:777738)
at async A.reexecuteCell (c:\Users\[]\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63072\out\client\extension.js:75:879007)
```

Using the Anaconda shell to open up jupyter notebook works perfectly, everything seems to be installed correctly and I made sure I had selected the right (and only) interpreter in Code, but it just refuses to work. Am I missing something? I've tried updating and reinstalling, nothing seems to work.

The only problem with my install seems to be opening the Python Interactive window, whether manually (via Ctrl + Shift + P) or attempting to run a cell in my code.

Comment: I had a lot of issues with Anaconda/VScode aswell! The problem turned out that Conda and PIP kinda mess eachother up. I ended deleting Anaconda/Spyder and just use VScode. You can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147353/exception-jupyter-command-jupyter-notebook-not-found-windows?noredirect=1#comment104521065_59147353 where I struggle with a bit of the same problem. Check my answer and see if that works for you

Comment: Also have you installed `jupyter` or `jupyterlab` ?

Comment: Yup, i have both. I checked your thread and I was missing pywin32, but the problem persists.

Comment: I've been running python in VSCode for over a year and it was working fine.  With this new version of VSCode, Jan. 2020, I am having all kinds of problems. I can't run my scripts from the VSCode terminal because I get a message that image not found. i don't know what image its referring to. If i put "cel"l on the first line andd try to run it the code just crashes.  If I hit the F5 button, which used to work, the program gives the no image found message. The only thing that works is that i get a  box on the status bar with a run arrow. When I click that arrow the program runs to completion.